# Read Information from Two Form

Tags: php, forms

I have two form in a page (Registration & Login), how can it read the information sent separately?

Answer (score 0):

For your submit buttons, if you use `<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">` and `<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In">` in your HTML, then in PHP either `$_POST['register']` will be set to "Register" or `$_POST['login']` will be set to "Log In", but not both. The button that you don't click on will not be present in your PHP's $_POST or $_GET arrays. You can use this to fork your code as follows:

```
//Check if 'login' parameter was passed into POST array
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    //Login code
}
else
{
    //Registration code
}
```

Let me know if this is helpful and makes sense :)